# Is there no real values of $p$ for which $-2x^2-(4-p)x+2p$ is always negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show that there are no real values of $p$ for which $-2x^2-(4-p)x+2p$ is always negative?

Comment: Is there an $x$ missing?

Comment: Definitely something (an $x$) is missing because when $p=0$ one has $-2x^2-4\lt 0$

Comment: Have you tried to use the quadratic formula? Please check your question.

Comment: Yes, a missing $x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discriminant of $-2x^2-(4-p)x+2p$ has to be negative for it to be always negative, i.e. no intersection with $y=0$,

$$(4+p)^2<0$$

which is impossible.

Comment: I think you mean discriminant.

Comment: @callculus thanks of spotting it

Comment: I think that the discriminant is $(p+4)^2$.

Comment: My discriminant works out to be  $(4+p)^2\lt 0   $.  They are the same?

Comment: @BenoitGaudeul isn't that exactly what is written?

Comment: Thanks, corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Solving your equation by the quadratic formula we get
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{4-p}{4}\pm\frac{4+p}{4}$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p=-4$. Your expression becomes:
$$
-2(x^2+4x+4)
$$
hence it is always non-positive. And that's the best you can have (see the other answers)

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be factorize to $$(x + 2)(p - 2x)$$

Which mean would always be $0$ at $x  = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, does there always exists a real value of $x$ for which
$-2x^2-(4-p)x+2p$ is positive?

If you complete the square...

\begin{align}
   -2x^2-(4-p)x+2p
   &= -2x^2+(p-4)x+2p \\
   &= -2\left[x^2-\dfrac{p-4}{2}x+\dfrac{(p-4)^2}{16} \right]
      +\dfrac{(p-4)^2}{8}+2p \\
   &= -2\left[x - \dfrac {p-4}{4} \right]^2+\dfrac {(p+4)^2}{8} \\
\end{align}

So, yeah, if you let $x = \dfrac {p-4}{4}$, then 
$-2x^2-(4-p)x+2p = \dfrac {(p+4)^2}{8}$